# Graphical error while installing

Tags: ati, graphics

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and even newer to this community. 
Ubuntu refuses to install and the screen goes nuts. Let me lay out a list of what happens.

1. Boot off USB and see grub boot menu with install or try Ubuntu.
2. Click any option to load.
3. Purplish screen comes up loading Ubuntu.
4. Screen goes weird colors, blank, or stripped.
5. Nothing else happens.

List of what I tried.

1. VGA vs dvi cord
2. Nomodeset or modeset=0
3. Fb=false
4. Tried same USB worked fine on Intel dell inspiron laptop, but want it on my desktop.

I have a friend with an AMD apu, but he has a GPU also, so it worked no problem for him. Do I need a GPU for my AMD to work?

---

### Specs

- no dedicated GPU just integrated.
- AMD a4-5400k
- fm2 motherboard
- rose will 5.1 surround card
- rose will dual band 900 WiFi card
- WD blue terabyte hard drive
- Kingston ram 8gig 1600hertz

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of different things.

At this point, it's probably easiest to try some more experiments to see if you can figure out which part of the stack is not working for you:

- Can you install with a text-only mode?
- has this computer worked running other operating systems?
- can you swap monitors?
- can you use a video card other than the integrated graphics?

Another idea is to gather more data: you may be able to connect a serial cable to the mothboard and see if there is a serial log. (I haven't tried this on a physical machine in years, though.)

Comment: 1. How to install text only mode? 2.yes windows XP and windows 7. 3. I swapped dvi to VGA no help, but I only have two of the same screens. 4. I don't have one, I was thinking of buying one. Do I need it? Amd apu has been fine for Minecraft running maxed out.